# running multiple variants of a webserver on different ports - cookies interfere

Tags: cookies

I have two instances of an identical service running on 2 ports - think of them as dev and test. They use session cookies that expire on inactivity.

When using the same browser, whenever I switch a tab from "dev" to "test", I have to log in again. Which becomes annoying after first few minutes. And this is because the HTTP cookies are tied to a server name, oblivious of the port.

I actually have multiple teams use the same test machine. My current solution is to use different browsers. I am also thinking of taking different domain names and map them to same IP address.

My question is - what am I missing, is there a better solution? Is it possible to make cookies port-aware (I don't have control over the software that names the cookies)?

Comment: Different hostnames; incognito sessions...

Comment: Andrew that's what we do. I wanted to explore other possibilities because my users are mostly non-technical.

Comment: The host names will do what you want.

Comment: Oh; when I say "host names" above, that of course includes different domain names.